# PDO update query does absolutely nothing

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

So yesterday I ran into this error which I can't seem to get a hang of. The piece of code below is supposed to make two posts in a recursive MariaDB table switch places.

`$cid` is the ID of the post that is supposed to switch place, up or down.
`$pid` is the parent ID.
`$ord` is which place the post has under the parent.
`$dir` is in which direction the post is supposed to be moved, up or down.

Then the post in the position that the first post is supposed to move to is taking the first posts initial place.

```
<?php

    $cid = isset($_GET['cid']) ? $_GET['cid'] : "";
    $pid = isset($_GET['pid']) ? $_GET['pid'] : "";
    $ord = isset($_GET['ord']) ? $_GET['ord'] : "";
    $dir = isset($_GET['dir']) ? $_GET['dir'] : "";

    if($cid == "" || $pid == "" || $ord == "" || $dir == "") die('nu gick det åt pipsvängen...');

    if($dir == "up") {
        $opos = $ord--;
    } elseif($dir == "down") {
        $opos = $ord++;
    } else {
        die('ingen riktning');
    };

    $ostmt = $dbh -> prepare("UPDATE csa_categories SET ordning = :onp WHERE foralder = :pid AND ordning = :oop");
    $ostmt -> bindValue(":onp", $ord);
    $ostmt -> bindValue(":pid", $pid);
    $ostmt -> bindValue(":oop", $opos);

    $ostmt -> execute();

    $cstmt = $dbh -> prepare("UPDATE csa_categories SET ordning = :cnp WHERE id = :cid");
    $cstmt -> bindValue(":cnp", $opos);
    $cstmt -> bindValue(":cid", $cid);

    $cstmt -> execute();

?>
```

This does absolutely nothing. I doesn't change anything in the table and there are no errors whatsoever.

Comment: echo your all values and check it's ok? if not any error may be updating elsewhere

Comment: Where is the connection?

Comment: @Rakesh: Yes, I've checked all my variables. Their value is exactly what I expect them to be.

Comment: Mihai: In another file that includes this file.

Comment: echo your exact query like this `UPDATE csa_categories SET ordning = $ord WHERE foralder = $pid AND ordning = $opos` and execute it with your mysql database software.

Comment: @StijnBernards: I've tried that as well, and this is the really weird thing. That works.

Comment: @Perplexor Hmm I've had the same error yesterday, let me think for a bit.

Comment: If it works directly in MySQL it means something is off with the PDO query or maybe the variables don't contain the data you think. But, it doesn't look like you would know it because you're not throwing exceptions or using `try { catch }` that I can see.

Comment: I use PHP style error reporting and there are no error outputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So today I finally made it! I was looking at the whole thing wrong. There where no flaws in the script, except for maybe the fact that I didn't comment it. Today I started commenting everything and gave my variables better names and it turns out, I've been thinking wrong. The update queries worked, but they updated the wrong lines, hence it seemed like nothing happened.

Here is the final solution:

```
<?php

    $absid = isset($_GET['cid']) ? $_GET['cid'] : "";   // ID of absolute row
    $parid = isset($_GET['pid']) ? $_GET['pid'] : "";   // Absolute row's parent ID
    $abspos = isset($_GET['ord']) ? $_GET['ord'] : "";  // Current position of absolute row
    $newrelpos = $abspos;                               // New position of relative row
    $dir = isset($_GET['dir']) ? $_GET['dir'] : "";     // Direction to move absolute row

    if($absid == "" || $parid == "" || $abspos == "" || $dir == "") die('missing variable(s)');

    // Generate absolute row's new position
    if($dir == "up") {
        $newabspos = $abspos - 1;
    } elseif($dir == "down") {
        $newabspos = $abspos + 1;
    } else {
        die('direction not set');
    };

    $relpos = $newabspos;   // Current position of relative row

    // Fetch relative row's ID
    $stmt = $dbh -> prepare("SELECT id FROM csa_categories WHERE foralder = :parid AND ordning = :pos");
    $stmt -> bindValue(":parid", $parid);
    $stmt -> bindValue(":pos", $relpos);
    $stmt -> execute();
    $row = $stmt -> fetch();

    $relid = $row['id'];    // Relative row's ID

    // Update absolute row
    $astmt = $dbh -> prepare("UPDATE csa_categories SET ordning = :newabspos WHERE id = :absid");
    $astmt -> bindValue(":newabspos", $newabspos);
    $astmt -> bindValue(":absid", $absid);
    $astmt -> execute();

    // Update relative row
    $rstmt = $dbh -> prepare("UPDATE csa_categories SET ordning = :newrelpos WHERE id = :relid");
    $rstmt -> bindValue(":newrelpos", $newrelpos);
    $rstmt -> bindValue(":relid", $relid);
    $rstmt -> execute();

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using either of these methods?

```
$ostmt = $dbh -> prepare("UPDATE csa_categories SET ordning = :onp WHERE foralder = :pid AND ordning = :oop");
$ostmt -> bindParam(":onp", $ord);
$ostmt -> bindParam(":pid", $pid);
$ostmt -> bindParam(":oop", $opos);
$ostmt -> execute();
```

or

```
$ostmt = $dbh -> prepare("UPDATE csa_categories SET ordning = :onp WHERE foralder = :pid AND ordning = :oop");
$ostmt -> execute(array(':onp'=>$ord,':'pid'=>$pid,':oop'=>$opos));
```

Also, does this statement produce any output:

```
$ostmt = $dbh -> prepare("SELECT ordning FROM csa_categories WHERE foralder = :pid AND ordning = :oop");
$ostmt -> bindParam(":pid", $pid);
$ostmt -> bindParam(":oop", $opos);
$ostmt -> execute();
```

Comment: I tried the first two suggestions without any luck.
The third query returns one row, as expected.

Comment: And you are sure that `print_r($dbh->errorInfo());` is empty?

Comment: It returns `Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => )` so no problem there.

Comment: what if you add `$dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING );` before calling `$dbh->prepare(<query>)` and then output `$dbh->errorinfo()` and `$ostmt->errorinfo();` ? (this should set the error mode of PDO from Error to Warning)

Comment: I already have `PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING`. Both statements and the handler returns the same, `Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => )`